# Flutter Listview swipe to change TabBar index

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented `TabBar` without `TabBarView`. I am using a single `ListView` as `body` since the layout after selecting a tab is same for all tabs.

What I want to achieve is, change the tab while swiping left / right in the listview. How can I do this?

**TabBar**

```
TabBar(
        indicatorWeight: 3,
        indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label,
        onTap: (index) {
          categoryId = newsProvider.categories[index].id;
          page = 1;
          fetchPosts(newsProvider);
        },
        isScrollable: true,
        tabs: [
          for (Category category in newsProvider.categories)
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 15),
              child: Text(
                category.name,
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18),
              ),
            ),
        ],
      ),
```

**body**

```
ListView.builder(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 60),
                    physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                    controller: _scrollController,
                    itemCount: newsProvider.posts.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (BuildContext context) =>
                                HabaruDetails(newsProvider.posts[index]),
                          ));
                        },
                        child: Container(
                          height: 200,
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10, right: 10, top: 10),
                          child: ClipRRect(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(7),
                            child: Stack(
                              children: [
                                Positioned.fill(
                                  child: Hero(
                                    tag: newsProvider.posts[index].id,
                                    child: FadeInImage.memoryNetwork(
                                        placeholder: kTransparentImage,
                                        fit: BoxFit.cover,
                                        image: newsProvider
                                            .posts[index].betterFeaturedImage.mediumLarge),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Container(
                                  height: 200,
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      gradient: LinearGradient(
                                          begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
                                          end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                                          colors: [
                                            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.0),
                                            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.95),
                                          ],
                                          stops: [
                                            0.0,
                                            1.0
                                          ])),
                                ),
                                Positioned.fill(
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    child: Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                          horizontal: 16, vertical: 30),
                                      child: Text(
                                        newsProvider.posts[index].title.rendered,
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                        textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          fontSize: 24,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          height: 1.7,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                  )
```

Comment: do you mean swiping horizontal or vertical ?

Comment: i want horizontal swiping

Comment: What I mean is that you only have 1 vertical list but you want to swap it horizontal, so the expected behaver is to change tabbar index and the list content by swiping or just change the tab index, sorry for the long questioning but I may help if I understand you better.

Comment: you got it right. i want to change tab index by swiping the list left or right. when tab index is changed I will call API to fetch new data and load into list. i don't want separate  list view for each tab.

Comment: I don't know if I should write a full answer for this but the solution is simple, you can warp the list with GestureDetector and detect the swiping or use swipedetector package here the link:https://pub.dev/packages/swipedetector, basically it will provide you with onSwipeLeft and onSwipeRight function so just some logic to pass the tab index will get you what you want.  if you need further explaining I can writhe the code for you.

Comment: This could work. One more thing. Does swiping move tab indicator along with the swipe if I use a gesture detector? If I use TabBar and TabBarView I can see the tab indicator moves while swiping. Will I get same result with this method?

Comment: Not really because when you are using TabBarView the value your passing to the indicator is double so that it moves smooth with the swiping but you can use the animateTo(index) method on the TabController while using GestureDetector or swipedetector however , this way the indicator will move but after the swipe is done to the index you choose, it's ok but also the only way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I think you still must use a TabBarView, but you can generate its children dynamically based on the categories list like below.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          bottom: TabBar(
            tabs: [...],
          ),
        ),
        body: TabBarView(
          children: newsProvider.categories.map(
                (e) => ListView.builder(...).toList(),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: But this method will create multiple pages in TabBarView. I need single page and swipe should only effect TabBar. Now, this is swiping pages as well.

Comment: TabBar can only be used in conjunction with TabBarVeiw, and TabBarViews must correspond to the order of the tabs in the TabBar, else it will throw an exception. Could you please explain more what you're trying to achieve? If you swipe the page shouldn't the content of the page get updated accordingly, or what is the expected behaviour?

Comment: What I really want is to change tab bar while swiping left or right on the body widget. Whether the body is a container or a ListView. I am thinking maybe I can use GestureDetector and change tab?

Comment: TabBarView method is also fine, but my problem is that when I  generate TaBarView children like in your answer, it generates the same page for all the tabs. I only need to load the content of the tab once the tab is selected. Not before that.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by `TabController` and `Listener`

First you can define a `TabController`. It need to be in StatefulWidget.

```
TabController _tabController;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _tabController = TabController(length: tabLenght, vsync: this);
}

TabBar(
  ...
  controller: _tabController,
  ...
)
```

Then you can add `Listener` class to the ListView. Save the clicked position and swiping distance in `onPointerDown`,`onPointerMove`,`onPointerUp` and
`onPointerCancel` (same as `onPointerUp`).

Change the tab by control the `offset` and index. Notice `offset` is in range (-1.0,1.0). You should animate by yourself if it reach the next index.

```
double startX;
double sensitivity = 0.01;

    ...
    child: Listener(
      onPointerDown: (event) {
        startX = event.position.dx;
      },

      onPointerMove: (event) {
        double newX = event.position.dx;
        double offset = ((startX - newX) * sensitivity).clamp(-1.0, 1.0);
        if (!_tabController.indexIsChanging)
          _tabController.offset = offset;
        if (offset == 1.0 &&
            _tabController.index < _tabController.length - 1) {
          _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index + 1);
          startX = newX;
        }
        if (offset == -1.0 && _tabController.index > 0) {
          _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index - 1);
          startX = newX;
        }
      },

      onPointerUp: (_) {
        if (_tabController.offset > 0.5 &&
            _tabController.index < _tabController.length - 1)
          _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index + 1);
        else if (_tabController.offset < -0.5 && _tabController.index > 0)
          _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index - 1);
        else {
          if (!_tabController.indexIsChanging)
            _tabController.offset = 0;
        }
      },

      onPointerCancel: (_) {
        if (_tabController.offset > 0.5 &&
            _tabController.index < _tabController.length - 1)
          _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index + 1);
        else if (_tabController.offset < -0.5 && _tabController.index > 0)
          _tabController.animateTo(_tabController.index - 1);
        else {
          if (!_tabController.indexIsChanging)
            _tabController.offset = 0;
        }
      },
      child: ListView.builder(
      ...
```

I think you want the drag effect like `TabBarView`? You can also check the source code inside `TabBarView`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, I think you're trying to create a tab bar that moves when the user scrolls down on the listview? If so, I have created an example of a class that uses a selection of tabs you can implement as a TabBar for your title in your AppBar whose controller is set to the TabBarController I have created above the build method. The listview is then set to the controller of the scrollcontroller which listens to the state of the tabbarcontroller.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,

        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {

  TabController _tabController;
  ScrollController _scrollController;


  void _scrollListener() {
    var index = (_scrollController.offset / 70).round();
    if(index >= choices.length){
      index = choices.lastIndexOf(choices.last);
    }
    if(index <= 0){
      index = 0;
    }
    if (index == choices.length)
      index = choices.length;
    if(mounted){
      setState(() {
        _tabController.animateTo(index, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeIn);
      });
    }

  }


  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _tabController = TabController(vsync: this, length: choices.length);
    _scrollController = ScrollController();
    _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);

  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _tabController.dispose();
    _scrollController.dispose();
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(

        title: TabBar(
          labelColor: Colors.black,
          unselectedLabelColor: Colors.black45,
          labelStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontFamily: 'Valera'),
          controller: _tabController,
          isScrollable: true,
          indicator: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
              color: Colors.transparent),
          onTap: (int index){
            setState(() {
              _scrollController.animateTo(index*80.0, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeIn);
            });
          },

          tabs: choices.map((Choice choice) {
            return Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
              child: Tab(
                text: choice.title,
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ),
      body: Container(

        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
            itemBuilder: (context, index){


            return ListTile(

            );

            }),

      ),

    );
  }
}



class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title});

  final String title;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'First Tab'),
  const Choice(title: 'Second Tab'),
  const Choice(title: 'Third Tab'),
  const Choice(title: 'Fourth Tab'),
  const Choice(title: 'Fifth Tab'),
  const Choice(title: 'Sixth Tab'),
];

class ChoiceCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const ChoiceCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);

  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(choice.title, style: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.black,
    ),
    );
  }
}
```